# Citrix VDI Windows 10 - VS Code > The Language Support for Java server crashed 5 times in the last 3 mintues

Tags: java, windows-10, vscode-extensions, citrix

I am having an issue analyzing an annoying issue with a Citrix Windows 10 VDI related to running any java code in VS Code.

OS: Win 10 20H2

VS Code 1.56.2

Java JDK 16 (8 is also installed but 16 is set as primary)

Extensions installed: Extension Pack for Java, Language support for java, maven for java, project manager for Java, Test runner for java

[Extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvRli.png)

The issue only happens when a non-admin user attempts to run any java code. Admin-level users do not get this issue.

sample code...

```
import java.util.scanner;

public class stuff{

  public static void main(string[]args){
    System.out.println("whatever else");
    /* Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String junk = keyboard.next();
    System.out.println("here it is"+junk); */
    System.out.println("wow.");
  }
}
```

even without running the code, the following error comes up:

```
The Language Support for Java crashed 5 times in the last 3 minutes. the server will not be restarted
```

logs:

```
{   message: 'WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.foreign, jdk.incubator.vector\r\n',

  level: 'info',

  timestamp: '2021-10-25 15:39:02.151'

} {   message: 'The Language Support for Java server crashed and will restart.',

  level: 'error',

  timestamp: '2021-10-25 15:39:05.387' } {   message: '[Info  - 3:39:05 p.m.] Connection to server got closed. Server will restart.',

  level: 'info',

  timestamp: '2021-10-25 15:39:05.388' }
```

I have attempted to elevate the permissions on the VsCode install folder, but because the java extensions are per-user - I am unsure which folder needs to have the right elevated.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: another similar error https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/743#issuecomment-446738302 looks like you can give "java.jdt.ls.vmargs" parameter to jvm and dig up the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't Do Any thing

First -
Uninstall all extensions

***imp - Don't Uninstall the Language Extension***

Then Restart The The Operating System